# Nested query GraphQL : Syntax error - iOS

Tags: ios, graphql, apollo

I am working with Apollo GraphQL and have to call nested query .But while call the Query in `.graphql` file it showing

> Syntax error : Expected Name, found {

Let me know how to call Nested query of GraphQL.
[image]

I have to call **getAllproduct{....}** query with the specified parameters.Here the ***FilterInput*** having the parameter as ***location*** with another pattern of query , so I don't know how to call this nested query.Anyone please help me to find out the solution.Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an argument is an Input Object Type (as opposed to a Scalar), you can include the fields of the Input Object Type by using curly brackets.

```
query MyProductsQuery {
  allProducts(
    pageNumber: "someString"
    filter: {
      title: "someOtherString"
      yearFrom: 1900
      location: {
        city: "yetAnotherString"
        state: "FL"
      }
    }
  ) {
    id
    # other product fields
  }
}
```

Of course, hardcoding those values in a `.graphql` file is not very helpful. You probably want to be able to swap those values out programatically. So here's what that same query looks like with variables:

```
query MyProductsQuery($pageNumber: String, $filter: FilterInput) {
  allProducts(pageNumber: $pageNumber, filter: $filter) {
    id
    # other product fields
  }
}
```

Your variables are passed in separately from your query and unlike your query, are **not** a GraphQL document. They are just JSON:

```
{
  "pageNumber": "someString",
  "filter": {
    "title": "someOtherString",
    "yearFrom": 1900,
    "location": {
      "city": "yetAnotherString",
      "state": "FL"
    }
  }
}
```